# Spark overwrite removes privileges of already existing tables in db2

Tags: apache-spark, db2

I am using a spark cluster to move parquet files into DB2 tables. These DB2 tables are defined and pre-made, but empty. It is also granted some privileges to some users. However, if I use this code in spark:

```
ds.get
    .coalesce(1)
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .jdbc(fullJdbcUrl, tableName, props)
```

to move the parquet data, it removes the grant status (in SYSIBMADM) and seems to remove and create a table, instead of using what already exists. I don't want to use SaveMode.Append because there may be data in it already in some scenarios. Is there a way I can delete the rows in a table inside Spark (So that I can use Append afterwards), or for it to be forced into using the already-created table? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.1, Spark added support for `truncate` JDBC DataFrameWriter.

```
ds.get
    .coalesce(1)
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .option("truncate", true)
    .jdbc(fullJdbcUrl, tableName, props)
```

Here is the detailed information about [truncate](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16463)

Comment: Does this works for Spark-3.1 as well

Comment: Yes, It works for Spark 3.1 as well.
You can check https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html for more detail.

Comment: I have a thread here - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027567/overwrite-mode-does-not-work-in-spark-sql-while-adding-data-in-db2)
Could you please help me in this?