# Overwrite mode does not work in spark-sql while adding data in db2

Tags: apache-spark, db2

EDIT:

I am new to spark and db2. I have data frame with me generated from various sources and I am storing that in a db2 table. I am using 'Overwrite' mode to do this, as I want the existing record to be removed automatically without any conditions.

By running this command -

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").jdbc(fullJdbcUrl, tableName, props)
```

it throws this error -
*com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501*

I understand the error codes.

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16463 ticket, they have updated the functionality, to either truncate or drop the table while overwriting the data, but when I try it out it still doesn't work.

```
df.write.option("truncate", "true").mode("overwrite").jdbc(fullJdbcUrl, tableName, props)
```

it throws this error -
*com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;*

Is there something I have missed in the code or they have added a new functionality.

I was also looking into - DataFrameWriterV2 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriterV2.html) but not sure how to implement it.

The version of Spark is - 3.1.1

Comment: It seems that there is an extra semicolon at the end of the sql statement, remove it and try again.

Comment: I don't know how the code converts this line - `df.write.option("truncate", "true").mode("overwrite").jdbc(fullJdbcUrl, tableName, props)` into SQL Query.